# Java thread id not changing

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm trying to unit test a class containing a ThreadLocal and wish to make tests not affect each other by starting a new thread in each test. However, they still do, and I don't understand why.

```
@Test
public void testThread() {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());
    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }
    }.run();
}
```

Output:

```
1
1
```

Can someone explain why the IDs are the same even though a new thread is started?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should call the start method on the thread, not the run method. If you call run, you are running it in the same thread.

Answer (score 1):

try to change

```
}.run();
```

with

```
}.start();
```